# Simple Moving Average on a .cat file with Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, types, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm trying to write a program that performs a moving average on a .cat file with ~500 float values, then saves the result to another file. The code works fine if I give in input an array like x=[1,2,3...] but when I try with the file I get the error message:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'`

May someone please help me?

```
import numpy as np

def movingaverage (values, window):
    weights = np.repeat(1.0,window)/window
    sma = np.convolve(values,weights,'valid')
    return sma

with open('Relative_flux.cat','r') as f:
    data=movingaverage(f,3)
    print(data)
```

Comment: You need to read from the file, format it to an array of floats and then pass it to your function. In which format are the floats saved in the file?

Comment: I imported them from a graph. They should be floats but I don't know how to verify.
1.0194280117841261
1.0920756955508646
1.1679216020846148
1.4219624708948044
1.4211211275688114
1.4627487052062624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` is a file handle, not the contents of the files. The contents must first be read, then formatted into an array of floats, before being handed to your function, which expects an array of floats.

Assuming the file is formatted in the way you mention in your comment:

```
data=movingaverage([float(x) for x in f.read().split()], 3)
```

`read()` reads the whole content of the file and returns it as a string.

`split()` splits the string at all whitespaces

`[float(x) for x in [...])` applies the conversion to `float` to every string, returning an array of floats.

This code will throw an exception if any of the entries in the file cannot be converted to float, or if the format is not consistently floating point numbers separated by whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you! It works now!
Now I just need to go back to the strings if I want to write the result in a new file.

Comment: @Vincenzo Conversion to a string is possible with `str(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your object `f` is an open file rather than an array of floating point values. You need to read lines from the file and load the floating point values into an array, which depends on the specific file format you're using.

Comment: Thank you Bruce, sorry but I'm a newbie on python. Is there a simple way to do it? I tried with a banal 'cast' but it doesn't work.